# rails generate scaffold command on Windows causes ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I used "rails generate scaffold project" to create an new web application. I already did this in the past on Linux and Mac OSX running other versions of rails and ruby and all worked fine, but this time I'm working on Windows 7. Here is my environment

```
C:\Users\user1\Company>ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24) [x64-mingw32]

C:\Users\user1\Company>rails -v
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Rails 4.1.0

C:\Users\user1\Company>
```

after I ran the scaffold command, I ran rake db:migrate and I was able to create my first project successfully. Then I can edit the project, but when I click update, I get the following error message

```
ArgumentError (When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.):
```

Full server log message

```
Started PATCH "/projects/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-29 05:16:33 -0700
Processing by projectsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"√", "authenticity_token"=>"gST6BUQNwOZQDYVj60DXLuFANv1JsM02YAIM+xYwt/M=", "commit"=>"Update project", "id"=>"1"}
  project Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects"  WHERE "projects"."id"= ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (1.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms

ArgumentError (When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.):

  app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:44:in `block in update'
  app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:43:in `update'

  Rendered C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (104.0ms)
```

Here is my "update" method (as was created automatically by the scaffold command)

```
# PATCH/PUT /projects/1
# PATCH/PUT /projects/1.json
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.update(project_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Update Successful!' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I tried removing the "PATCH/" keyword, but no luck. I replaced the whole method with the following (this worked for my other application, but not this time on Windows)

```
# PATCH/PUT /projects/1
# PATCH/PUT /projects/1.json
def update
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])

  if @project.update_attributes(params[:project])
    flash[:notice] = "Update Successful!"
  end
  respond_with(@project)
end
```

but this did not make any difference.

I also tried (I found this by browsing SO)

```
# PUT /projects/1
# PUT /projects/1.json
def update
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.update_attributes(params[:project])
      format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Update Successful!' }
      format.json { head :ok }
    else
      format.html { render action: "edit" }
      format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
```

but no success either

Here are the other working methods (all as automatically generated by "rails generate scaffold" command, and they all work fine)

```
# GET /projects
# GET /projects.json
def index
  @projects = project.all
end

# GET /projects/1
# GET /projects/1.json
def show
end

# GET /projects/new
def new
  @project = project.new
end

# GET /projects/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /projects
# POST /projects.json
def create
  @project = project.new(project_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.save
      format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Creation Successful!' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Why is "rails generate scaffold" command not working on Windows and working fine on Linux and Mac OSX?

**Update 1**

Here are the other methods that were automatically created by "rails generate scaffold" command

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  <other methods listed above : index, show, new, edit, create, update, and destroy>

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def project_params
      params[:project]
    end
end
```

**Working Code after making the changes suggested by Kirti Thorat**

This is what worked for me

```
# PATCH/PUT /projects/1
# PATCH/PUT /projects/1.json
def update

@project = Project.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.update(project_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_project
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:UnitMgtAddress)
  end
```

Comment: Post your `project_params` method

Comment: @Pavan : thanks for your prompt response. I updated by question under "Update 1", as is, without any changes from my side.

Comment: Currently what attributes does the `Project` hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just created a scaffold without any other fields. So your `projects` table simply has 3  default fields `id`, `created_at` and `updated_at`. Because of which in your `update` action when you do:

```
if @project.update(project_params)
```

Or

```
if @project.update_attributes(params[:project])
```

you get error as `update` and `update_attributes` require a `Hash` as an argument and `params[:project]` is nil. Look at your `params` hash from server log

```
{"utf8"=>"√", "authenticity_token"=>"gST6BUQNwOZQDYVj60DXLuFANv1JsM02YAIM+xYwt/M=", "commit"=>"Update project", "id"=>"1"}
```

**It doesn't have a key `project`.**

### Possible Solutions

**Without adding new fields**

If you are not planning to add any new fields in your `projects` table then there is no point in having an `update` action as what field would you update on?

**With adding new fields**

You can add new fields to your `projects` table like `name`, `duration`, etc as per your requirement (By creating a migration to add new fields).

After this you would just need to update the `project_params` method as below:

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:name, :duration)
end
```

Comment: Just curious.If the `params[:project]` in `project_params` changed to `params.permit(id: [])`,it works?

Comment: Nope. It won't work. As firstly `id` is not passed as an `array` and secondly this will create problem when OP actually adds some fields in `projects` table.

Comment: Thanks for the brief explanation. I'm just getting used with strong parametrs.

Comment: I still wonder what could be the solution for this type of peculiar problems.

Comment: Anyways its 1:00 AM here in India.Good morning.I better sleep now.:)

Comment: @KirtiThorat : thanks a lot for your help. I implemented the changes you suggested and it worked for me, but now I have another issue ; see my update under "Working Code". http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23380844/ajax-request-causing-param-is-missing-or-the-value-is-empty-error

Comment: Glad to help :). And I see that your question is resolved now.

Comment: @KirtiThorat : in fact, the solution looked good at the beginning, but it does not really do what I want. My form is full of buttons and input fields and I want to call get_config each time the user presses a button or changes some input, and having one button outside the form to do that does not really work for me. I'm still looking for a better way to call get_config from different places in the form, closer to my original design.